# Android Studio - Android tasks have already been created - it is not possible to continue configuring the model

Tags: android

Error:(25, 0) Android tasks have already been created.
This happens when calling android.applicationVariants,
android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants.
Once these methods are called, it is not possible to
continue configuring the model.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'

```
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lionasys.routineer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

    })

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.truizlop.sectionedrecyclerview:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'

    compile 'me.srodrigo:androidhintspinner:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.brnunes:swipeablerecyclerview:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.truizlop.sectionedrecyclerview:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'

    compile 'me.srodrigo:androidhintspinner:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.brnunes:swipeablerecyclerview:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'



    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev243-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }



    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev243-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


}
```

}
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: what do u want exactly??

Comment: Error:(25, 0) Android tasks have already been created. This happens when calling android.applicationVariants, android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants. Once these methods are called, it is not possible to continue configuring the model.

Comment: this is my error message when try to build the project. want to solve it @Roy

Comment: post the entire log cat plzz

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Android tasks have already been created.
     This happens when calling android.applicationVariants,
     android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants.
     Once these methods are called, it is not possible to
     continue configuring the model.
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: here it is @Roy

Comment: now  just after the `apply plugin: 'android'`, try again : apply plugin `android.applicationVariants.all`

Comment: not working.. :( @Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
    }
```

should go as child of `buildTypes`. You have it on the outside. Try moving it in and there should be no problems.

Comment: buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
            }
        }